# Apache 310 redirect with wildcard URL

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, 301-redirect

I'm trying to redirect this...
http://www.wfmc.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=878&qid=3686395  -- Where '&qid=3686395' varies from link to link.  How can I redirect everything that looks like this 'http://www.wfmc.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=878' where it will take care of everything after the 878 to another website.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your apache is configured to serve 'www.wfmc.org'. In your vhost or .htaccess file (assuming you have Options FileInfo allowed for your domain's documentroot):

RewriteRule ^administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=878(.*) http://someURL/someFile?$1 [L]

that should work.

Comment: This is the exact string I used.  RewriteRule ^administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=878(.*) http://www.bpm.com/managing-enterprise-performance-webinar.html?$1  ---------  didn't work.  got rid of the [L] since there was stuff underneath it in a different section of the .htaccess.

Comment: try 'http://bpm.com'. also, do you have a rewrite log enabled? it might be helpful in determining rewrite issues.

Comment: also, I suck. I forgot the [R=301] flag, so I would use [R=301, L]. I'm not sure what stuff below this rewrite rule you'd have that you'd want to run after issuing the redirect.